# My node.js server doesn't work when launched from another directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get my node.js server to launch on startup.  If I'm in my server folder and type:

```
node server.js
```

It runs just fine and launches python scripts that are in the same folder.

But if I run it from outside that directory or from an init script, like this:

```
node /home/servers/server.js
```

It starts, and receives calls, but is not running the python scripts as it is supposed to.

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: I can clearly see your mistake. It's right in the middle of all that code you posted.

Comment: Did you resolve this? If not, possibly post the beginning code of your node.js so we can see what python scripts and the paths

Answer (score 2):

When you run `node`, it references all filesystem calls from the directory node was *called* from, instead of the directory that `app.js` is in, so if you're trying to `require('./myfile')`, `myfile.js` will need to be in the directory you're running `node` in.

Run this simple script from different directories to see it in action (it runs `ls`, lovingly copied from [here](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs)):

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("ls -la", puts);
```

As to your Python problem, you should develop an empirical location to call `app.js` from, and use that when locating scripts.

Comment: That's good to know.  Forgive me, I'm a noob... Could you explain the solution just a bit more.  I've tried moving my server.js file and linking to my other files, but I still have the same problem.  Any idea why node works like this??

Comment: Added some more detail.  If you need more help, feel free to join us in the [JS chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript).

Comment: Is it possible to solve this by setting an environment variable? For example: `NODE_PATH=Chat node Chat/server.js`

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the directory to ensure you're where you need to be. Just add something like this to the top of your file:

`__dirname` points to the directory containing the current file. For this example I will be assuming the following repo structure:

```
repo/
    src/
        index.js
    package.json
```

And inside index.js I will put:

```
const path = require('path');

process.chdir(path.join(__dirname));
```